# Inheriting a field from a model in django

Tags: django, django-models

I'd like the user_image, email and name field in my Comments model to be inherited from the  UserProfile model. I tried using UserProfile.profile_image as the base class in my ForeignKey field, and it obviously didn't work. I know that's wrong, but any alternative would do.

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    bio = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    profile_image = models.FileField(upload_to="profile_pic", blank=True, null=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments', null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    user_image = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_date']

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} comment made by {}'.format(self.body, self.name)
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to actually inherit AbstractUser class only to provide userprofile information. Simply create new model called UserProfile(do not touch AbstractUser) and make OneToOneField pointing to the User model. Read more here: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/23/how-to-add-user-profile-to-django-admin.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to associate each comment with an user, simply

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments', null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # ...

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} comment made by {}'.format(self.body, self.user)
```

You can then access the user's image, etc. with `comment.user.profile_image` etc..

This has the advantage of deduplicating data, but if the user changes their email or other information, it will be "retroactively" changed to comments too. If you want to avoid that, it's best to just copy the data into similar fields on the model (but keep the `user` field too, for bookkeeping purposes):

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments', null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_profile_image = models.FileField(upload_to="profile_pic", blank=True, null=True)
    user_email = ...
```

Comment: The second option feels good to me, but just to inquire, will I be allowed to do this as in your second example: ```user_profile_image = user.profile_image```

Comment: That didn't work. It wasn't recognizing profile_image as a field of the user object.

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant when assigning. You could *maybe* use something like `user_profile_image = User._meta.get_field("profile_image")` but you'd be better off just copying the fields.